# Adding column alias values used in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I sum the total of these column aliases when used in a case statement?

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN TYPE = 'FEES' THEN AMOUNT END) AS Fees, 
    (CASE WHEN TYPE = 'PENALTY' THEN AMOUNT END) AS Penalty, 
    (CASE WHEN TYPE = 'INTEREST' THEN AMOUNT END) AS Interest, 
    SUM(Fees + Penalty + Interest) AS Total
FROM MyTable
```

Note: There are more types than just the 3 summed, so `sum(Amount)` doesn't give the required result.

Comment: Yes I noticed :) thats why we ask for a [mre] - to avoid people spending time trying to solve a problem that isn't the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the sum:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN FRESHNESS = 'ROTTEN' THEN ORANGES ELSE 0 END) AS Bad_Oranges
    , SUM(CASE WHEN FRESHNESS = 'ROTTEN' THEN APPLES ELSE 0 END) AS Bad_Apples 
    , SUM(CASE WHEN FRESHNESS = 'ROTTEN' THEN ORANGES + APPLES ELSE 0 END) AS Bad_Total
FROM Fruit
```

Bases on your new requirements it would be:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'FEES' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Fees 
    , SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'PENALTY' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Penalty 
    , SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'INTEREST' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Interest 
    , SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('INTEREST','PENALTY','FEES') THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Total
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: If you have a bunch of different ways that bad is defined for different fruit, I'd probably add a table of (fruit,condition) and left join to it rather than having to add the wording into your queries.